# Very stupid algebra question... why is 'a' even?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am watching the MIT course "Mathematics for Computer Science" on YouTube [right here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8HKWUWS-lA).  At about 7:20, We have the following equation:

$ 2b^2 = a^2 $

He then asks, "What do we know about $ a^2 $?"  He then says, "If $ a^2 $ is even then $ a $ must be even.  However, any squared number is even.  Why did he say t his?

Comment: If $a$ wasn't even, it wouldn't have a factor of 2 in it.  But then $a^2$ wouldn't either.

Comment: Any squared number is even? Not at all. Pick any odd number and square it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every squared number is even.  For example, $3^2=9$, and 9 is not even.

The product of any two odd numbers is odd.  In particular, the square of an odd number is odd.

If $a$ were odd, then its square would be odd.  But we know that $a^2$ is even.  So $a$ cannot be odd.  But every integer is either even or odd.  So $a$ must be even.

---

An even number, by definition, is one that you can get by multiplying  some integer by 2.  For example, the even number 10 is the result of multiplying the integer 5 by 2.  Since $b^2$ is an integer, the result of multiplying it by 2, namely $2b^2$, is even.  Since $a^2$ is equal to an even number, namely $2b^2$, it is also even.

Comment: And $ a^2 $ has to be even because the left hand side of the equation is multiplied by 2?

Comment: $a^2$ is even because it is equal to $2b^2$, which is even.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. Think about 3 times 3 which is 9. Not even.

Answer (score 0):

If you watch the video carefully, you'll find that you misheard. That's not what the professor said.

The reasoning here is that because $2b^2 = a^2$, $a^2$ is a multiple of $2$. We know from unique prime factorization that $a$ must therefore be a multiple of $2$. Then it follows that $a^2$ must be a multiple of $4$.